# property holds for all bases except 2

Tags: binary

For any base $n$, for $n > 2$ the following holds:

$1/(n-1) = 0.111...$

However in base 2 this doesn't hold. It's just 1. It's obvious why that is you have $1/1$, but I always get uneasy with non-0 and non-1 exceptions in an otherwise flawless rule. Is there any way to shed some light on this?

Comment: What's the rule for $1/(n-(n-1))$?  Which rule wins at $n=2$?

Comment: @EricTowers I don't get it, $n/(n−(n−1))$ is just $n$ right?

Comment: Stuttered on the "$n$"s.  Fixed now.

Comment: @EricTowers Now it's just always $1$. I still don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation also holds in base $2$. Note that that claim is the same as the $0.9999\ldots=1$ in the world of ten-finger people.